# (bash) Delete elements from xml if a value is missing

Tags: bash, sed, xmlstarlet

I'd like to remove some elements in a big xml file, if a value is missing.

I have found a topic where it says how to extract the elements where the value is present but not the other way around. Solution could be sed or xmlstartlet but I can't figure it out.

```
 xmlstarlet ed -d '//eslXmlDto[.//itemAssociations]' < file1.xml >> file2.xml
```

Here is the file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<screens>
    <screenXmlDto>
        <articleCodeType>EAN</articleCodeType>
        <creationDate>2017-04-25T12:23:18.746+02:00</creationDate>
        <domain>toto.tata</domain>
        <screenCode>16201000032884264000</screenCode>
        <itemAssociations>
            <itemCode>2118550000000</itemCode>
            <position>1</position>
        </itemAssociations>
    </screenXmlDto>
    <screenXmlDto>
        <articleCodeType>EAN</articleCodeType>
        <creationDate>2016-07-27T03:59:17.328+02:00</creationDate>
        <domain>toto.tata</domain>
        <screenCode>17201000030538183370</screenCode>
    </screenXmlDto>
    <screenXmlDto>
        <articleCodeType>EAN</articleCodeType>
        <creationDate>2016-07-26T12:28:20.815+02:00</creationDate>
        <domain>toto.tata</domain>
        <screenCode>17201000030538091000</screenCode>
        <itemAssociations>
            <itemCode>4008033444958</itemCode>
            <position>1</position>
        </itemAssociations>
    </screenXmlDto>
</screens>
```

Here is the output I want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<screens>
    <screenXmlDto>
        <articleCodeType>EAN</articleCodeType>
        <creationDate>2017-04-25T12:23:18.746+02:00</creationDate>
        <domain>toto.tata</domain>
        <screenCode>16201000032884264000</screenCode>
        <itemAssociations>
            <itemCode>2118550000000</itemCode>
            <position>1</position>
        </itemAssociations>
    </screenXmlDto>
    <screenXmlDto>
        <articleCodeType>EAN</articleCodeType>
        <creationDate>2016-07-26T12:28:20.815+02:00</creationDate>
        <domain>toto.tata</domain>
        <screenCode>17201000030538091000</screenCode>
        <itemAssociations>
            <itemCode>4008033444958</itemCode>
            <position>1</position>
        </itemAssociations>
    </screenXmlDto>
</screens>
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//screenXmlDto[not(itemAssociations)]' file1.xml
```

- `-d` - delete action
- `//screenXmlDto[not(itemAssociations)]` - xpath expression to select all `screenXmlDto` nodes which don't have `itemAssociations` node as a child

---

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<screens>
  <screenXmlDto>
    <articleCodeType>EAN</articleCodeType>
    <creationDate>2017-04-25T12:23:18.746+02:00</creationDate>
    <domain>toto.tata</domain>
    <screenCode>16201000032884264000</screenCode>
    <itemAssociations>
      <itemCode>2118550000000</itemCode>
      <position>1</position>
    </itemAssociations>
  </screenXmlDto>
  <screenXmlDto>
    <articleCodeType>EAN</articleCodeType>
    <creationDate>2016-07-26T12:28:20.815+02:00</creationDate>
    <domain>toto.tata</domain>
    <screenCode>17201000030538091000</screenCode>
    <itemAssociations>
      <itemCode>4008033444958</itemCode>
      <position>1</position>
    </itemAssociations>
  </screenXmlDto>
</screens>
```